# F.conv3d RuntimeError: Input type (c10::Half) and bias type (float) should be the same

Tags: pytorch

I tried to use c3d to extract features from my data, I print out my input_data.dtype and got tenso.float32. According to the official documnet of nn.conv3d, the input datatype seems correct, but I encounter with this error:

```
F.conv3d  RuntimeError: Input type (c10::Half) and bias type (float) should be the same
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ming/chmp/ContAwareMotionPred/exp_gta_stage1_cont.py", line 267, in <module>
    mp.spawn(main, nprocs=args.gpus, args=(cfg, args))
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 241, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method="spawn")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 197, in start_processes
    while not context.join():
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 158, in join
    raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid)
torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException: 

-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 68, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/ming/chmp/ContAwareMotionPred/exp_gta_stage1_cont.py", line 225, in main
    train(i, gpu, model,optimizer,scheduler,dataset, cfg, args, **params)
  File "/home/ming/chmp/ContAwareMotionPred/exp_gta_stage1_cont.py", line 96, in train
    cont_dct_est = model(joints[:, :t_his].reshape([bs, t_his, -1]).transpose(0, 1),
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1523, in forward
    else self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1359, in _run_ddp_forward
    return self.module(*inputs, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[index]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/chmp/ContAwareMotionPred/models/pvcnn_dct.py", line 73, in forward
    sdf_embedding = c3d(sdf_volume)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/chmp/ContAwareMotionPred/models/C3D.py", line 26, in forward
    x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 610, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ming/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 605, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv3d(
           ^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Input type (c10::Half) and bias type (float) should be the same
```

What I did to the data:

1. The data is originally numpy array
2. I used torch.tensor(my_data).float() to change the datatype into tensor.float32
3. I've printed "my_data.dtype" out, and get "tensor.float32" as a result. So the datatype should be correct.
   Here is my torch version:torch
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suTZ8.png)
   I'm using torch2.2.1+cu118